# How can I figure out the number of ways that more men than women are selected?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Twelve men and ten women apply to attend a special event. Six names are selected.  In how many ways could more men than women be selected?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: Add up the three probabilities of disjoint events which equal your compound event.